# how should i reply to this mail from professor?

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate, email, assistant-professor

I got a positive reply from the professor, how should I reply politely?
This is the response from my professor:

"let me go through and get back to you on the article "

Currently, the professor is preoccupied with a lot of work but still helping me, so considering the situation can anyone suggest a draft of the email that I can send to this professor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Their email doesn't seem to require an answer. What exactly do you want to communicate?

Answer (score 3):

If the exchange took place in a hallway, your response would probably be just "OK, thanks". But an email that says only that adds nothing to the conversation and is a (minor) disruption.

I'd suggest that you just wait for a while and see what develops.